# Website Search and Scraping

Tags: html, search, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I travel a lot for business and frequent kayak.com and it got me thinking about how kayak can accomplish the search and scraping of all these websites.

I can understand taking the data from the loaded HTML pages, but how would they accomplish the  back end search, of Expedia.com for example, with out the end user seeing Expedia's site?

Answer (score 0):

I've built dozens of meta-searches like this. There is a couple options:

1. Become an affiliate: often a site will give you an API you can submit a search to, and get a response quickly. Most of the time, you'll get a little kick-back for a referral.
2. Scrape the target site: odds are you don't want to try to get an airline's entire itinerary for the future, so the best plan here is to have a routine that will take your user's search, feed it to the sites, and get results back. Your front end will need to handle asynchronous results or plan on making the user wait a long time.

Comment: Jason, Thank you for the answer.  How?/What would you use to take a query and feed it to the site and get the answers... all on the back end with out the user seeing this?

Comment: In my case, I'd use jQuery, and create a web-form for the user to fill in the search, and submission of that form would 1) send the user to a results page (with a waiting dialog), and 2) launch multiple concurrent scraping agents to run the search on the various suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually depending on affiliate marketing channels for your SQL Results is not a good idea.  I would find a way to bulk insert the data on your end and build a search engine around the data feed results.  Your dependence on others will affect the quality of a site your building.

Also think of it like a CAR, the more options you add to it the more there is to break.

Checkout Avoli.com.